# Silverlight, Child Windows, and the Back button

Tags: silverlight, navigation, back

I am using a Silverlight Navigation style application.

Is there a way to back the browser's Back button close a ChildWindow instead of going back a page?
Right now the Back button goes back while leaving the ChildWindow open.

**EDIT**

This is what I would like my back-stack to look like:

- Edit Title (ChildWindow)
- View-Record (Page)
- Home (Page)

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about your application I can't suggest anything concrete, but you'd need to hook the display of the ChildWindow in with the navigation somehow - which isn't really how it works.

Comment: I'm not doing anything special. It is just the Navigation project template, a couple of pages, and a ChildWindow control.

Comment: Think this link could help you: [Prevent Browser Back Button for Silverlight with Confirm Dialog](http://mrpanot.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/prevent-browser-back-button-for-silverlight-with-confirm-dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is canceling the navigation and then pushing the old hash tag back into the title.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CharacterSheet.HasOpenDialogs)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>{
                HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark = NavigationService.CurrentSource.ToString().Replace(@"\", @"/");
                CharacterSheet.CloseDialogs();
            }));
        }
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }
```